# IRkernel cannot find jupyter (which is installed in Anaconda) Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, anaconda, jupyter, ubuntu-16.04

All packages installed fine ('pbdZMQ', 'repr', 'devtools', 'IRdisplay', 'IRkernel').

`IRkernel::installspec()`

But the above command gave an error "Jupyter or IPython 3.0 has to be installed".
jupyter is installed in Anaconda (python 2.7.11) and works with both Python & Julia.

Comment: If you are using anaconda, `conda install -c r r-irkernel` is the easiest way to get a working r-kernel.

Comment: Thanks. I installed a Python 3.5 environment with jupyter & r-essentials. `conda create -n renv python=3.5`. `conda install -n renv jupyter`. `conda install -n renv -c r r-essentials`.

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it with two steps. In my case it was a path problem. First, in RStudio, `print(system.file("kernelspec", package = "IRkernel"))`. Then, I used the output to run this in a terminal: `jupyter kernelspec install --replace --name ir --user /home/lincoln/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.3/IRkernel/kernelspec`. Adapt it with the output of the first command.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in the tutorial this morning -- on the same platform.

See my [pull request to the documentation here](https://github.com/ledell/useR-machine-learning-tutorial/pull/3) -- it worked for me once I added the `pip` / `pip3` created `bin/` directory to the `$PATH`.  However, I used plain Python and not the overbearingly large Anaconda installation.

Comment: Anaconda added /bin to the $PATH in .bashrc. `which jupyter` points to this directory.

Comment: Good point.  Maybe you then just need to (re-)source `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

I initially received the same error as the OP using Ubuntu 16.04

As a result of @Dirk pull request to the documentation, I believe this note has been added to the [Installation Instructions](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/).

```
On OS X, be sure to execute this in R started from the Terminal, not the R App!
(This is because the R app doesn’t honor $PATH changes in ~/.bash_profile)
```

After starting R from the Terminal in Ubuntu, I was able to follow these instructions and hence did not receive the error anymore:

```
install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'evaluate', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 'devtools', 'uuid', 'digest'))
devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
```

After entering the above commands in the R shell, I opened up Jupyter-Notebook from the Terminal (not the R shell). R is now an option along with Python 3.

Then within the notebook, I re-entered the following commands:

```
install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 'evaluate', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 'devtools', 'uuid', 'digest'))
devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
IRkernel::installspec()
```

While the first two commands returned 'Non-zero exit status warnings' the `IRkernel::installspec()` successfully executed with no errors.

R is now working properly in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I'm still getting the same error (cannot find jupyter) after starting R in Terminal with "sudo R" in Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: @RockPereira I have updated the response to address your concern. It seems that I was getting the same error as you, but R still appeared in Jupyter and is now functioning properly.